# Checking if filenames contain a string

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In my project,I have a product list in first column on a excel sheet and I regularly download product images from a website and than store them in a Folder differently named for every project. When downloading process is over, I delete the image files which are unnecessary.

After deleting process , I want to know how many image left for every product on folder.

Examples:

My list of product name in first column >>>
[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k020J.png)

My image folder >>> [click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIiKU.png)

What I want is the number of image on a folder for every product >>>
[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMbaV.png)

If I make excel formula to write the number of images for every product on second column ,next to corresponding product name cell, I will able to easily see any lack of image for any product. After that, I will report the list of products which have zero image.

All names of images consist of two parts "productname" and "_*", * is a number. Because product name is not the same as name of image files, values in number of image column is must be the number of image whose name contain product name.

Does it doable or not? I have very basic knowledge of VBA.

**Here what I get when I try to use method of** **@Miguel_Ryu**

Function I wrote >>> [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNopc.png)

My Folder >>> [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRNBi.png)

Error I got >>> [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hheeI.png)

Module >>>[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVXSm.png)

Comment: What kind of file is 'productimages'? How many files of this kind do you have and how are they distributed? What did you try to achieve your desired result?

Comment: What does it mean for a file to contain other files? Do you mean that productimages is a *folder*? Where are these file names? Are they somewhere in the spreadsheet already or do you need VBA to iterate through the folder? This question is unclear.

Comment: @JohnColeman sorry for my bad description. I meant image files on a folder. I edited the description.

Comment: @Jochen I edited the description.

Comment: @BahadırYalın, have you tried my answer? It should work for what you need. Do you need help implementing it?

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu I tried to use it. I insert a new module and paste your code to there. Then use write the function on cell B2  and revised for my path and string like that =loopThroughFilesCount("C:\Users\yalinbah\Desktop\boyner\görseller2\Tekstil",A2)    But an error window is appeared. Now, I am looking for a solution on internet

Comment: @BahadırYalın, It can work like that, you just need to add '\' to you path like : `=loopThroughFilesCount("C:\Users\yalinbah\Desktop\boyner\gör‌​seller2\Tekstil\",A2)` , and it should work.

Comment: @BahadırYalın, just saw your edit, where did you put the `Function`?

Comment: @Miguel_Ryu on excel developer bar>>visual basic>>insert>>module , I edited desc. again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function, it returns the count of files containing `strToFind`.

You can call it like this: 
`fileCount = loopThroughFilesCount("C:\yourPath\yourFiles\", "yourString")`

```
Function loopThroughFilesCount(dirFolder As String, strToFind As String) As Double

    Dim filePath As Variant
    filePath = Dir(dirFolder)
    While (filePath <> "")
        If InStr(filePath, strToFind) > 0 Then
            filesCount = filesCount + 1
        End If
        filePath = Dir
    Wend

    loopThroughFilesCount = filesCount

End Function
```

Edit: 
To run the above as a macro.

```
Sub countFiles()

    Set last = Range("A:A").Find("*", Cells(1, 1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious)

    For n = 2 To last.Row
        Cells(n, 2).Value = loopThroughFilesCount("C:\Users\yalinbah\Desktop\boyner\gör‌​‌​seller2\Tekstil\", Cells(n, 1).Value)
    Next

End Sub

Function loopThroughFilesCount(dirFolder As String, strToFind As String) As Double

    Dim filePath As Variant
    filePath = Dir(dirFolder)
    While (filePath <> "")
        If InStr(filePath, strToFind) > 0 Then
            filesCount = filesCount + 1
        End If
        filePath = Dir
    Wend

    loopThroughFilesCount = filesCount

End Function
```

Comment: I put the screenshots on description, could you look at them. Do I write function wrong.  I expect to write my folder path and select cell to insert a string(A2 cell)  then function will show the number of image files which contain string in cell A2. After that I will copy and paste the function to cells on column B

Comment: @BahadırYalın, I edited the code to run as a macro, give it a try and tell me if you get any error or something.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works and I simply understand the code. It reads first column and write the number on second column.If I enhance the code is it possible to make macro ask me cells and folder path on a window so I can run macro when my product names are not placed on first column. Let say my list on B1 to B5 and I dont want macro to run on after cell B5, and numbers are placed on C1 to C5.

Comment: Yes it is, you'll need to change the `Sub`, you can do something like `InputBox` or a `Custom Form` to get the range. Then adjust the length of the `For n = 2 to *your last row*` and adjust the column on the `Cells(n, *your chosen column*).Value`. If you's like to make another question I'll help you out (or someone else will beat me to it :p)

Comment: Thank you, I will try on my own. I think,   I must open new question for a implementation like on my previous comment. Do you notice why as a function I cant run this code on one cell?

Comment: It's better to open another question in this kind of situation so people on the community with similar problems can find it if they search. To be honest I didn't, it works perfectly well on mine. Give it another try, might be something was miss-typed. BTW depending on you version of Excel formulas might be separated by comma `,` of semicolon `;`. `P.S. If your happy with the answer to your question please mark as accepted :D`