# Retrieve Folder path based on cell value (match cell value to folder in directory)

Tags: excel, vba

I appreciate all the help with my last question [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72190715/retrieve-file-path-based-on-cell-value-match-cell-value-to-file-name-in-directo/72191217#72191217)

Previous code to find file name based on cell contents. Perhaps it can be edited slightly to work for this new request?

```
    Sub ParseFiles()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long
  Const foldPath As String = "C:\Users\User1\Downloads\Test*"
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = 2 To lastRow
        sh.Range("B" & i).Value = GetFilePath(foldPath, sh.Range("A" & i).Value)
  Next
End Sub

Function GetFilePath(dirFolder As String, strToFind As String) As String
     GetFilePath = Dir(dirFolder & "*" & strToFind & "*.*")
End Function
```

I would like to find if a folder exists in a directory, which is likely within a subfolder of that directory. The folder name may have characters in front or behind and won't match the cell value perfectly, but it will contain the cell value. Example:
Folder name is 'customer 601892 20220105' but the cell value is '601892'

Here we have a directory (Test) where I'm searching if a folder name exists based on the contents of A1, A2, etc... if it exists, I'd like the output in B1, B2 with the folder path and folder name.

[image]

This is the ideal output.

[image]

Comment: Not sure I correctly understand your question... So you do not need a subfolder of a main folder, knowing its partial name. You need that subfolder to be extracted from one of the main folder subfolders?

Comment: Yes that's correct. There's the main folder (Test), subfolders (for years like 2022, 2021, 2020, 2019) and folders within those folders.

Comment: Can be more occurrences of the same partial string? If so, returning the first occurrence is OK?

Comment: Returning the first occurrence is perfect!

Comment: OK. I will post an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the next way. Since you cannot use `Dir` in two different loops, in the `Sub` I will use "Scripting.FileSystemObject", to iterate between the main folder subfolders:

```
Sub extractSubfolderPathFromSubfolders()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, i As Long, fldName As String
    Dim FSO As Object, fld As Object, subFld As Object
    Const foldPath As String = "C:\Users\User1\Downloads\Test\"
    
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fld = FSO.GetFolder(foldPath)
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        For Each subFld In fld.SubFolders
            fldName = getFoldPath(CStr(subFld), sh.Range("A" & i).value)
            If fldName <> "" Then
                sh.Range("B" & i).value = subFld & "\" & fldName
            End If
        Next
    Next i
End Sub
```

And a function able to return a directory knowing its partial name. It is called by the above sub:

```
Function getFoldPath(dirFolder As String, strToFind As String) As String
    Dim fldName As String
    If Right(dirFolder, 1) <> "\" Then dirFolder = dirFolder & "\"
    fldName = Dir(dirFolder & "*" & strToFind & "*", vbDirectory)
    Do While fldName <> ""
        If fldName <> "." And fldName <> ".." Then
            ' Use bitwise comparison to make sure dirFolder is a directory.
            If (GetAttr(dirFolder & fldName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                getFoldPath = fldName: Exit Function
            End If
        End If
        fldName = Dir
    Loop
End Function
```

I need to close my computer now. If something does not work as you need, please try explaining why. I will adapt the code tomorrow...